# How to use Redshift COPY with non hard-coded keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

Following is what I tried, but it didn't work. I think the problem is the generated keys are only generated for the scope of EC2 instance. So when Redshift tries to call COPY command with that then its not recognized.

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        return new StringBuilder("COPY ").append(tmpPrefix)
                .append(tableName)
                .append(" FROM '")
                .append(filePath)
                .append("' WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=")
                .append(credentialProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId())
                .append(";aws_secret_access_key=")
                .append(credentialProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey())
                .append("' JSON 'auto' GZIP ACCEPTINVCHARS ' ' TRUNCATECOLUMNS TRIMBLANKS;")
                .toString();
```

Following is the error i got

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId....
```

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Do you have IAM Role setup for your ec2 instance from where you trying to execute a COPY command?

Comment: EC2 has IAM role to access specific buckets. But redshift is access via JDCB commands (though JBOSS), which users Redshift credentials.

Answer (score 2):

You are using IAM Role  ( which creates you set of temporary credentials + token ).

When you execute a COPY command using temp creds (access, secret, token ) you have provide token as well:

`credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<temporary-access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<temporary-secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-token>';`

Take a look at the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html